# Why do we need PHY Interface between DDR Controller and DRAM Memory?

Tags: memory, pci-express, computer-architecture, ddr, dram

1. Is it required to have PHY in all the systems, if not what happens ?
2. if PHY is removed can we still pull the data from DRAM memory using the DDR controller ? if yes, then why do we need to have PHY Interface.

Answer (score 1):

1. No it's not required. You could set up a wireless connection between them.
2. We can pull data from DRAM when it is connected to a power supply. Each memory cell periodically needs to be refreshed to retain its bit value.